# Django-Tinymce not loading

Tags: django, web, tinymce, tinymce-plugins, django-tinymce

I have included django-tinymce module in my django 3.1 project. However, the tinymce editor disappeared from my pages and I don't know why. When I run the project in my localhost I get a 404 on init_tinymce.js, a folder that is not in my project and not specified in the django-tinymce project.

I hardly touched anything but it suddenly did not show on my pages. Here is the log from my console:

```
[08/Jun/2021 08:32:26] "GET /letter_head_edit/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14367
[08/Jun/2021 08:32:26] "GET /static/django_tinymce/init_tinymce.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[08/Jun/2021 08:32:26] "GET /static/django_tinymce/init_tinymce.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
```

Here is my settings.py file config:

```
TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(STATIC_URL, "js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js")
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, "js/tinymce")
TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = True

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    "height": "500px",
    "width": "auto",
    "menubar": "file edit view insert format tools table help",
    "plugins": "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor searchreplace visualblocks code "
    "fullscreen insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount spellchecker",
    "toolbar": "undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontselect fontsizeselect formatselect | alignleft "
    "aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist checklist | forecolor "
    "backcolor casechange permanentpen formatpainter removeformat | pagebreak | charmap emoticons | "
    "fullscreen  preview save print | insertfile image media pageembed template link anchor codesample | "
    "a11ycheck ltr rtl | showcomments addcomment code",
    "custom_undo_redo_levels": 10,
    "language": "es_ES",  # To force a specific language instead of the Django current language.
}
```

And finally how I load TinyMCE on my forms. I use model forms for this.

I import it first:

```
from tinymce import models as tinymce_models
```

Then use it on one of the models:

```
content = tinymce_models.HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)
```

URLs.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
     
    path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
]
```

Finally, on the template:

```
<div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-0">
            {{ form.media }}
        {{ form.content|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specifically need to change the default `TINYMCE_JS_URL` and `TINYMCE_JS_ROOT` settings, don't set them in your project. Did you include  'tinymce' in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Thanks for checking the issue. I am not sure I understand the first part of your answer. Does it mean I don't have to include the TINYMCE_JS_URL and TINYMCE_JS_ROOT? Secondly, I did include 'tinymce' in my INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Thanks Claude, I got this after tinkering with the code.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue with my set-up was that when I am using the "lazy" way to load TinyMCE into django by using:

```
from tinymce import models as tinymce_models

content = tinymce_models.HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Is that I don't need to set the URL if I will use the default path TinyMCE expects. (Insight by Claude)

Also the 'django_tinymce' folder will generate the 'init_tinymce.js' file. I am not sure whey it didn't do it in the beginning but, after running collectstatic on my local machine, I could see the folder and the file.

Maybe someone else might have a formal answer to this.